# Nest rows of dataframe as an array column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks more or less like this:

```
| id | category | value | item_id |
|----|----------|-------|---------|
| 1  | 1        | 1     | 1       |
| 2  | 2        | 2     | 2       |
| 3  | 1        | 3     | 1       |
| 4  | 2        | 4     | 2       |
```

In this case, some of the categories must be considered sub-categories in some parts of the code (computation up to this point is similar regardless of the hierarchy, and thus they are all on the same table). However, now they must be nested according to a certain set of rules, defined in a separate dataframe:

```
| id | children |
|----|----------|
| 1  | [2,3]    |
| 2  | null     |
| 3  | null     |
```

This nesting depends on the `item` column. That is, for each row, only those entries with the same item value which have a subcategory have to be nested. Which means that the categories 2 and 3 for item 1 have to be nested under the entry with id 1. If output to JSON, the result should look like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "item": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "value": 1,
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "item": 1,
        "category": 2,
        "value": 2
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "item": 1,
        "category": 3,
        "value": 3
    }]
},

{
    "id": 4,
    "item": 2,
    "category": 1,
    "value": 4,
    "children": []
}]
```

While fairly simple to implement using my own code, I would like to achieve this nesting using the PySpark Dataframe API. So far, here is what I have tried:

Join the two tables so that the list of children for a certain row is added as a column:

```
df_data = df_data.join(df_rules, df_data.category == df_rules.id, "left")
```

After some coalescing, here is the result:

```
| id | category | value | children |
|----|----------|-------|----------|
| 1  | 1        | 1     | [2,3]    |
| 2  | 2        | 2     | []       |
| 3  | 1        | 3     | []       |
| 4  | 2        | 4     | []       |
```

Now, I would like to apply some sort of transformation so that I get something like this:

```
| id | category | value | item | children                |
|----|----------|-------|------|-------------------------|
| 1  | 1        | 1     | 1    |[(2,2,2,1),(3,3,3,1)]    |
| 2  | 2        | 2     | 1    |[]                       |
| 3  | 1        | 3     | 1    |[]                       |
| 4  | 2        | 4     | 1    |[]                       |
```

That is, rows with ids 2 and 3 are nested into row 1. The rest receive an empty list, as there are no matches. Afterwards the subcategories can be removed, but that is trivial to implement.

I am struggling a bit to implement this. My first thought was to use something like this:

```
spark.sql("SELECT *, ARRAY(SELECT * FROM my_table b WHERE b.item = a.item AND b.category IN a.children) FROM my_table a")
```

However, as soon as I add a `SELECT` statement to `ARRAY` it complains. I have also considered window functions or UDFs, but I am not sure how I could proceed with those, or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think found a way to do this. Here is an MCVE using Pandas to create data. It assumes an already initialized Spark session

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
columns = ['id', 'category', 'value', 'item_id']
data = [(1,1,1,1), (2,2,2,2), (3,3,3,1), (4,4,4,2)]

spark_data = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=columns))

rules_columns = ['category', 'children_rules']
rules_data = [(1, [2, 3]), (2, []), (3, [])]

spark_rules_data = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=rules_data, columns=rules_columns))
```

First, perform a left join with the rules to apply:

```
joined_data = spark_data.join(spark_rules_data, on="category", how="left")
joined_data = joined_data.withColumn("children_rules", F.coalesce(F.col("children_rules"), F.array()))

joined_data.createOrReplaceTempView("joined_data")


joined_data.show()


+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------+
|category| id|value|item_id|children_rules|
+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------+
|       1|  1|    1|      1|        [2, 3]|
|       3|  3|    3|      1|            []|
|       2|  2|    2|      2|            []|
|       4|  4|    4|      2|            []|
+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------+
```

Join the table with itself according to the rules in the `children` column

```
nested_data = spark.sql("""SELECT joined_data_1.id as id, joined_data_1.category as category, joined_data_1.value as value, joined_data_1.item_id as item_id,
             STRUCT(joined_data_2.id as id, joined_data_2.category as category, joined_data_2.value as value, joined_data_2.item_id as item_id) as children
             FROM joined_data AS joined_data_1 LEFT JOIN joined_data AS joined_data_2 
                 ON array_contains(joined_data_1.children_rules, joined_data_2.category)""")
nested_data.createOrReplaceTempView("nested_data")
nested_data.show()

+---+--------+-----+-------+------------+
| id|category|value|item_id|    children|
+---+--------+-----+-------+------------+
|  1|       1|    1|      1|[3, 3, 3, 1]|
|  1|       1|    1|      1|[2, 2, 2, 2]|
|  3|       3|    3|      1|       [,,,]|
|  2|       2|    2|      2|       [,,,]|
|  4|       4|    4|      2|       [,,,]|
+---+--------+-----+-------+------------+
```

Group by category value and aggregate the `children` column into a list

```
grouped_data = spark.sql("SELECT category, collect_set(children) as children FROM nested_data GROUP BY category")
grouped_data.createOrReplaceTempView("grouped_data")
grouped_data.show()

+--------+--------------------+
|category|            children|
+--------+--------------------+
|       1|[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3...|
|       3|             [[,,,]]|
|       2|             [[,,,]]|
|       4|             [[,,,]]|
+--------+--------------------+
```

Join the grouped table with the original one

```
original_with_children = spark_data.join(grouped_data, on="category")
original_with_children.createOrReplaceTempView("original_with_children")
original_with_children.show()

+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------------+
|category| id|value|item_id|            children|
+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------------+
|       1|  1|    1|      1|[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3...|
|       3|  3|    3|      1|             [[,,,]]|
|       2|  2|    2|      2|             [[,,,]]|
|       4|  4|    4|      2|             [[,,,]]|
+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------------+
```

Here is the tricky bit. We need to remove the entries in `children` with `NULL` values. I tried to do a `CASE` statement with an empty array, casting to `'array<struct<id:bigint,category:bigint,value:bigint,item_id:bigint>>` (this value comes from `original_with_children.dtypes`:

```
[('category', 'bigint'),
 ('id', 'bigint'),
 ('value', 'bigint'),
 ('item_id', 'bigint'),
 ('children',
  'array<struct<id:bigint,category:bigint,value:bigint,item_id:bigint>>')]

array_type = "array<struct<id:bigint,category:bigint,value:bigint,item_id:bigint>>"
spark.sql(f"""SELECT *, CASE WHEN children[0]['category'] IS NULL THEN CAST(ARRAY() AS {array_type}) ELSE children END as no_null_children 
        FROM original_with_children""").show()
```

This raises the following exception (only relevant bit shown):

---

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

~/miniconda3/envs/sukiyaki_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:


~/miniconda3/envs/sukiyaki_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:


Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'array()' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast array<string> to array<struct<id:bigint,category:bigint,value:bigint,item_id:bigint>>; line 1 pos 57;
...
```

I could not figure out a way to create an empty array of the right type (casting does not work, as there is no conversion between the default, array of string, and an array of structures). Instead, here is my approach:

The order of the fields changes on every call and that surprisingly causes a type mismatch, so it is necessar to query it every time
    array_type = next(value for key, value in original_with_children.dtypes if key == 'children')

```
empty_array_udf = F.udf(lambda : [], array_type)

aux = original_with_children.withColumn("aux", empty_array_udf())
aux.createOrReplaceTempView("aux")
```

There must be a better way to create an empty column with this complicated type. The UDF causes an unnecessary overhead for such a simple thing.

```
no_null_children = spark.sql("""SELECT *, CASE WHEN children[0]['category'] IS NULL THEN aux ELSE children END as no_null_children 
          FROM aux""")
no_null_children.createOrReplaceTempView("no_null_children")
no_null_children.show()

+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------------+---+--------------------+
|category| id|value|item_id|            children|aux|    no_null_children|
+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------------+---+--------------------+
|       1|  1|    1|      1|[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3...| []|[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3...|
|       3|  3|    3|      1|             [[,,,]]| []|                  []|
|       2|  2|    2|      2|             [[,,,]]| []|                  []|
|       4|  4|    4|      2|             [[,,,]]| []|                  []|
+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------------+---+--------------------+
```

Remove unnecessary columns:

```
result = no_null_children.drop("aux").drop("children").withColumnRenamed("no_null_children", "children")
```

Remove nested entries from the top level

```
nested_categories = spark.sql("""SELECT explode(children['category']) as category FROM removed_columns""")
nested_categories.createOrReplaceTempView("nested_categories")
nested_categories.show()

+--------+
|category|
+--------+
|       2|
|       3|
+--------+


result = spark.sql("SELECT * from removed_columns WHERE category NOT IN (SELECT category FROM nested_categories)")
result.show()

+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------------+
|category| id|value|item_id|            children|
+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------------+
|       1|  1|    1|      1|[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3...|
|       4|  4|    4|      2|                  []|
+--------+---+-----+-------+--------------------+
```

And the final JSON result looks as desired:

```
result.toJSON().collect()


['{"category":1,"id":1,"value":1,"item_id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"category":2,"value":2,"item_id":2},{"id":3,"category":3,"value":3,"item_id":1}]}',
 '{"category":4,"id":4,"value":4,"item_id":2,"children":[]}']
```

Prettified:

```
{
   "category":1,
   "id":1,
   "value":1,
   "item_id":1,
   "children":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "category":2,
         "value":2,
         "item_id":2
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "category":3,
         "value":3,
         "item_id":1
      }
   ]
}

{
   "category":4,
   "id":4,
   "value":4,
   "item_id":2,
   "children":[

   ]
}
```